# Get count of Referer domain from users Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i get count of all domain from users from database

example:

```
id      user       refurl
1      ultraman    https://google.com/asd/a3sd/asd.html
2      Kingogthe   https://google.be/asd/as2d/asd.html
3      biomanliv   https://google.ttr/asd/a1sd/asd.html
4      amanrras    https://google.mmo/asd/a4sd/asd.html
5      talllos     https://yahoo.cosdm/asd/a5sd/asd.html
6      bicenoza    https://yahoo.gd/asd/as6d/asd.html
7      Linliveagi  https://www.bing.cp/asd/as6d/asd.html.
8      fkbareshuy  https://www.bing.cdd/asd/as6d/asd.html
```

The **output** to be like:

---

4 from google

2 from yahoo

2 from bing

etc.

---

*I tried  `"SELECT COUNT(*) ......"`* but didn't work how i wanted to

and i tried to use parse_url['host']

```
$url = parse_url['host'];
$getdomainonly = explode('.',$url);

echo $getdomainonly[0]; 
//here you get domain without com net Example: https://google.com/asd/aasd to only google
```

but i don't know how to use this php code with **SQL** to get the output

---

if you want to know:

I run script on php 5.6 but i can change it if there is answer for 7.0,7.1 or 7.2

I use MySql to saved data

---

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: *"I tried  "SELECT COUNT(*)"* - That's one problem. I'd use `COUNT(col) as x` using an alias. Or, you can use `num_rows` - `rowCount()` depending on the api used to connect with.

Comment: this is not duplicate of that please remove as duplicate  @IdontDownVote

Comment: sure is, thats how i would solve it. thats how it was answered below

Comment: i saied i use Mysql

Comment: that possible dupe almost looks like what Gordon posted below. Edit: @GordonLinoff would you agree or disagree? if I hammer this, you going to be all over me? Someone flagged as such before your answer was in.

Comment: ....well, now I've no reason to feel guilty, heh.

Comment: i can delete? when it comes to mysql\db Gordon Linoff is a god.

Comment: Delete? Why @IdontDownVote?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have tagged php, I'm going to guess that you are using MySQL.  If so, you can do:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(refurl, '.', 1), '//', -1) as domain,
       count(*)
from example
group by domain;
```

Comment: "I use MySql for database" good 'guess' :-)

Comment: what do you mean is there wrong if there is please tell me @IdontDownVote

Comment: @game_over_new use and accept the answer, move on, i think we are have language difficulties here.

Comment: you are not make it easy now i want to know from you please don't escape the question @IdontDownVote

Comment: Is there a way to input from biggest to smallest to show like this 4 from google and the second to show 2 from yahoo etc i tried `order by domain DESC` didn't work for me **Edit:** i found it `order by count(domain) DESC`

Comment: There is something is getting wrong when they url is https://`www`.google.com/asdhasd/asdas.html is getting output www  @Gordon_Linoff

Comment: @game_over_new . . . This answers the question *that you asked*.  If you have other sample data, ask a *new* question and provide appropriate data.  This question is pretty clearly about the substring following `//`.

Comment: i didn't say is not working, is working very good but this thing `www` is getting